# Pingdom page load test

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pageload

I have a problem which has only recently appeared and cannot figure out what may be causing it.

Up until recently, if I tested my pagespeed on Pingdon, I was getting around 800ms load time...

Now it has suddenly shot up to 13s...

I notice that when I visit a page (any page on my site), the header loads instantly but the body takes a bit of time to show which appears to be holding things up.

Previously different parts of the body would load at different rates which seemed to offer a much quicker load speed.

I have noticed that the waterfall diagram on pingdom shows every aspect of my page loading quickly bar 2 elements

`jquery-3.1.1.js` and `bootstrap.js`

both of these are shown in red and file size says 0B
They both display the yellow "wait" line but appear that they are never received which suggests to me that the files are being requested, the system is waiting for a period before ignoring them.

It does not tell me, however, what these files are associated with and I am scared to search for them, find them and delete them in case they are required for anything.

Could anyone shed any light on this please?

[Pingdom screenshots:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQN51.png) .

[Pingdom screenshots:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpTXt.png)
.

As you will see from the pics, everything loads quick but then there are 2 long yellow bars which do not end with with green (received) and the titles are in red and I am assuming these are the ones linked to the connection errors in the first pic

Comment: showing your pingdom report would be helpfull

Comment: @MateuszJ  I have added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Just try to open those URLs in your browser:

https://www.supplementgenie.co.uk/js/jquery-3.1.1.js
https://www.supplementgenie.co.uk/js/bootstrap.js

You can see those URLs are producing **HTTP Error 404** which means those files cannot be found on the server (on your web-site). So, you wouldn't be able to delete those files as they are not there in the first place. This seems to be a case an improperly configured hosting or a web-site. **Contact your developer** (in the first place) or your hoster. Maybe you don't even need those lines in the header of your web-site and can simply remove them from it.

P.S. If you open the source code of your page you can see your web-site is already loading jQuery from Google's CDN:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Same with Boostrap:

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I built the website myself (couldnt afford a developer lol) I have a feeling the files came from a plugin which I no longer use but I am unsure how to stop my site calling them when the page loads. it happens on every page

Comment: It's hard to say without having access the source code of your web-site. You could probably simply check the source code and search for the names of the missing files: jquery-3.1.1.js and bootstrap.js, and then delete the lines in the code that refer to them. If it was a plugin that has added those lines to your web-site maybe temporary deactivating plugins can help see which one was responsible for it.